# Passing a groovy object to a Java method

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I'm creating an object in java and setting it as a variable in GroovyShell.

```
// in java file, create class and shell
//
class Foo {
   void addSomething(Bar bar) { ... }
}

shell.setVariable("foo", new Foo())
```

In groovy I create an new class that extends from Bar and try to call `addSomething()`.

```
class MyBar extends Bar
{
    ...
}

foo.addSomething(new MyBar())
```

This fails with something like:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static foo.addSomething() is applicable for argument types: (MyBar) values: [MyBar@4ba7aa7]
```

Maybe the static part is throwing me off, but I don't understand the error.  I thought it may have to do with passing a groovy-created subclass to addSomething, but I also tried passing an object. I created from a java class.  Can I not pass groovy-created objects to a java class I set as a variable?

Comment: Assuming that it's the same Bar class referenced in both classes, then the only possible problem is the scope of addSomething() in class Foo. Remember, it's in Java and therefore the scope matters (as it will be called from outside the package)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was the variable name I was passing to groovy matched the file name and the file name was stomping over the variable.  By renaming the file or variable, I could pass down the object without any problems.